# How do I read comments on ads via Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to usa a system user to read comments on my ads via the Facebook marketing api.

It works fine to read comments on a post that is published on a page, as long as I use the Facebook page access token.

However, when I try to do the same with an ad, using **effective_object_story_id**, I get no comments.

When trying to read the effective_object_story_id with a **GET** request, I only receive the fields id, created_time and message, where message is "{{product.brand}}".

And when trying to read the comments I just get an empty array (even though I can see that there are many comments if i just browse to facebook.com/{effective_object_story_id})

The System User has full access to the page (actor) and ad account.

Is this still some kind of permission problem or am I trying to access the comments the wrong way (by a GET request to /{effective_object_story_id}/comments using a page access token)?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?